# User profile page

Tags: templating

I'm looking to setup a profile page, displaying a users details (address etc) and they're current membership status (which will be down the Stripe Payments plugin.)

I'm having some trouble getting the routes / template to work properly. I have set a new route `user/*` -> `user/_user`

I have then created that template and set a 'Manage Account' link with

```
{% set users = craft.users %}
{% for user in users %}
<a href="/user/{{ user.username }}">Manage Account</a>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I'm being told the template doesn't exist. I'm not sure at which part the template is not being found - is the route or the link incorrect?

Appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a routing issue, the route should look like:

```
'user/*' =>  ['template' => 'user/_user']
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped solve it!